# What does delta_length mean in this context?

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

and thanks for looking at this question!

I'm trying to extend a force directed graph layout to not just lay out a graph in 3d (which the following implementation does a fine job of) but to also do so dynamically, letting me adding graphs after some time has passed.

My first step in this process has been to copy down the code, and make some minor improvements like applying vectors where before it calculated forces, offsets and positions individually for x, y and z.

```
/**
    Thanks, @author David Piegza
    Gutted by Joshua Moore
 */

var Layout = Layout || {};

Layout.ForceDirected = function(graph, options) {
  this.options = options || {};

  this.attraction_multiplier = options.attraction || 5;
  this.repulsion_multiplier = options.repulsion || 0.75;
  this.max_iterations = options.iterations || 1000;
  this.graph = graph;
  this.width = options.width || 200;
  this.height = options.height || 200;
  this.finished = false;

  this.callback_positionUpdated = options.positionUpdated;

  this.EPSILON = 0.00001;
  this.attraction_constant;
  this.repulsion_constant;
  this.forceConstant;
  this.layout_iterations = 0;
  this.temperature = 0;
  this.graph.layout = this;

  // performance test
  this.mean_time = 0;
};

  /**
   * Initialize parameters used by the algorithm.
   */
Layout.ForceDirected.prototype.init = function() {
    this.graph.prepare();
    this.stop_calculating();

    this.finished = false;
    this.temperature = this.width / 10.0;
    this.forceConstant = Math.sqrt(this.height * this.width / this.graph.nodes.length);
    this.attraction_constant = this.attraction_multiplier * this.forceConstant;
    this.repulsion_constant = this.repulsion_multiplier * this.forceConstant;
};

  /**
   * Generates the force-directed layout.
   *
   * It finishes when the number of max_iterations has been reached or when
   * the temperature is nearly zero.
   */
Layout.ForceDirected.prototype.generate = function() {

    var nodes_length = this.graph.nodes.length;
    var edges_length = this.graph.edges.length;

    if(this.layout_iterations < this.max_iterations || this.temperature > 0.000001) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();

        // calculate repulsion
        for(var i=0; i < nodes_length; i++) {
            var node_v = this.graph.nodes[i];
            var k = 0;

            node_v.layout = node_v.layout || {};
            node_v.position = node_v.position || {};
            node_v.data = node_v.data || {};

            if(k++==0) {
                node_v.layout.offset_x = 0;
                node_v.layout.offset_y = 0;
                node_v.layout.offset_z = 0;
            }

            node_v.layout.force = 0;
            node_v.layout.tmp_pos_x = node_v.layout.tmp_pos_x || node_v.position.x;
            node_v.layout.tmp_pos_y = node_v.layout.tmp_pos_y || node_v.position.y;
            node_v.layout.tmp_pos_z = node_v.layout.tmp_pos_z || node_v.position.z;

            for(var j=i+1; j < nodes_length; j++) {
                var node_u = this.graph.nodes[j];
                if(i != j) {
                    node_u.layout = node_u.layout || {};
                    node_u.layout.tmp_pos_x = node_u.layout.tmp_pos_x || node_u.position.x;
                    node_u.layout.tmp_pos_y = node_u.layout.tmp_pos_y || node_u.position.y;
                    node_u.layout.tmp_pos_z = node_u.layout.tmp_pos_z || node_u.position.z;

                    var delta_x = node_v.layout.tmp_pos_x - node_u.layout.tmp_pos_x;
                    var delta_y = node_v.layout.tmp_pos_y - node_u.layout.tmp_pos_y;
                    var delta_z = node_v.layout.tmp_pos_z - node_u.layout.tmp_pos_z;

                    var delta_length = Math.max(this.EPSILON, Math.sqrt((delta_x * delta_x) + (delta_y * delta_y)));
                    var delta_length_z = Math.max(this.EPSILON, Math.sqrt((delta_z * delta_z) + (delta_y * delta_y)));

                    var force = (this.repulsion_constant * this.repulsion_constant) / delta_length;
                    var force_z = (this.repulsion_constant * this.repulsion_constant) / delta_length_z;

                    node_v.layout.force += force;
                    node_u.layout.force += force;

                    node_v.layout.offset_x += (delta_x / delta_length) * force;
                    node_v.layout.offset_y += (delta_y / delta_length) * force;

                    if(i==0) {
                        node_u.layout.offset_x = 0;
                        node_u.layout.offset_y = 0;
                        node_u.layout.offset_z = 0;
                    }
                    node_u.layout.offset_x -= (delta_x / delta_length) * force;
                    node_u.layout.offset_y -= (delta_y / delta_length) * force;

                    node_v.layout.offset_z += (delta_z / delta_length_z) * force_z;
                    node_u.layout.offset_z -= (delta_z / delta_length_z) * force_z;
                }
            }
        }

        // calculate attraction
        for(var i=0; i < edges_length; i++) {
            var edge = this.graph.edges[i];
            var delta_x = edge.source.layout.tmp_pos_x - edge.target.layout.tmp_pos_x;
            var delta_y = edge.source.layout.tmp_pos_y - edge.target.layout.tmp_pos_y;
            var delta_z = edge.source.layout.tmp_pos_z - edge.target.layout.tmp_pos_z;

            var delta_length = Math.max(this.EPSILON, Math.sqrt((delta_x * delta_x) + (delta_y * delta_y)));
            var delta_length_z = Math.max(this.EPSILON, Math.sqrt((delta_z * delta_z) + (delta_y * delta_y)));

            var force = (delta_length * delta_length) / (edge.data.force ? edge.data.force * this.attraction_constant : this.attraction_constant);
            var force_z = (delta_length_z * delta_length_z) / (edge.data.force ? edge.data.force * this.attraction_constant  : this.attraction_constant);

            edge.source.layout.force -= force;
            edge.target.layout.force += force;

            edge.source.layout.offset_x -= (delta_x / delta_length) * force;
            edge.source.layout.offset_y -= (delta_y / delta_length) * force;
            edge.source.layout.offset_z -= (delta_z / delta_length_z) * force_z;

            edge.target.layout.offset_x += (delta_x / delta_length) * force;
            edge.target.layout.offset_y += (delta_y / delta_length) * force;
            edge.target.layout.offset_z += (delta_z / delta_length_z) * force_z;
        }

        // calculate positions
        for(var i=0; i < nodes_length; i++) {
            var node = this.graph.nodes[i];

            var delta_length = Math.max(this.EPSILON, Math.sqrt(node.layout.offset_x * node.layout.offset_x + node.layout.offset_y * node.layout.offset_y));
            var delta_length_z = Math.max(this.EPSILON, Math.sqrt(node.layout.offset_z * node.layout.offset_z + node.layout.offset_y * node.layout.offset_y));

            node.layout.tmp_pos_x += (node.layout.offset_x / delta_length) * Math.min(delta_length, this.temperature);
            node.layout.tmp_pos_y += (node.layout.offset_y / delta_length) * Math.min(delta_length, this.temperature);
            node.layout.tmp_pos_z += (node.layout.offset_z / delta_length_z) * Math.min(delta_length_z, this.temperature);

            var updated = true;
            var x = (node.position.x - node.layout.tmp_pos_x) / 10,
                y = (node.position.y - node.layout.tmp_pos_y) / 10,
                z = (node.position.z - node.layout.tmp_pos_z) / 10;
            node.position.set(x, y, z);
            node.data.draw_object.position.set(x, y, z);

            // execute callback function if positions has been updated
            if(updated && typeof callback_positionUpdated === 'function') {
                this.callback_positionUpdated(node);
            }
        }

        // update lines
        for(var i=0; i<edges_length; i++){
            var edge = this.graph.edges[i];
            edge.data.layout.geometry.vertices[0] = edge.source.position;
            edge.data.layout.geometry.vertices[1] = edge.target.position;
            edge.data.layout.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        }

        this.temperature *= (1 - (this.layout_iterations / this.max_iterations));
        this.layout_iterations++;

        var end = new Date().getTime();
        this.mean_time += end - start;

    } else {
        if(!this.finished) {        
        console.log("Average time: " + (this.mean_time/this.layout_iterations) + " ms");
    }
        this.finished = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

  /**
   * Stops the calculation by setting the current_iterations to max_iterations.
   */
Layout.ForceDirected.prototype.stop_calculating = function() {
    layout_iterations = this.max_iterations;
};
```

Sorry for this long piece of code, I figured it'd be best to give you the most context possible. Still reading? You're awesome!

So my specific question is this:

within the third outer for loop within generate(), `delta_length` and `delta_length_z` are calculated separately, like this:

```
var delta_length = Math.max(this.EPSILON, Math.sqrt(node.layout.offset_x * node.layout.offset_x + node.layout.offset_y * node.layout.offset_y));
var delta_length_z = Math.max(this.EPSILON, Math.sqrt(node.layout.offset_z * node.layout.offset_z + node.layout.offset_y * node.layout.offset_y));
```

What do delta_length and delta_length mean? Why are they calculated seperately? Is there some vector math I can apply to this?

Thanks in advance,

Joshua

Answer (score 1):

delta_length and delta_length_z don't have to be calculated separately. Three.js defines length as `Math.sqrt((delta.x^2)+(delta.y^2)*(delta.z^2))`, which means I can probably just use `delta.length()` for `delta_length` and ignore `delta_length_z`.